Gleichzeitigkeit ausdrücken: Soll man „wenn" oder „als" benutzen?
Um, z.B, das folgende auf Deutsch überzutragen

I listen as he comes up the stairs

soll man „wenn" oder „als" benutzen?

Ich höre zu, als er die Treppen steigt/hochkommt

oder

Ich höre zu, wenn er die Treppen steigt/hochkommt

Im allgemeinem, wie drückt man gegenwärtige Gleichzeitigkeit auf Deutsch aus?

Anmerkung: Der Beispielsatz "Ich höre zu, als er die Treppe hochkommt." klingt für mich sehr unidiomatisch. Ich glaube mein Problem ist, dass "zuhören" entweder ein Dativobjekt braucht ("Ich höre dem Vogelgezwitscher zu"), oder ohne Objekt die Bedeutung hat, dass man einem mündlichen Vortrag oder einem Musikstück aufmerksam folgt. Für mich funktionieren "Ich höre, als er die Treppe hochkommt" und "Ich höre zu, wie er die Treppe hochkommt" (mit etwas andere Semantik) besser.

Zuhören wird für Geschichten, Musik, Vorträge usw. benutzt, nicht für das reine Wahrnehmen, daher:

Ich höre ihn die Treppe hochkommen.

oder

Ich höre, wie er die Treppe hochkommt.

Für ein vergangenes hochkommen:

Ich hörte, als er die Treppe hochkam.


Ich hörte, dass er die Treppe hochkommt.

Vom kleinen Versatz der Schallgeschwindigkeit abgesehen sind aber Ursache eines Geräuschs und dessen Wahrnehmung i.d.R. gleichzeitig. Eine Ausnahme wären eine Audioaufzeichnung oder das Hören vom Hörensagen:

Ich hörte, dass Du für morgen zugesagt hast.


Ich werde hören, was Du mir auf den AB gesprochen hast.

Wenn wird konditional eingesetzt:

Ich höre (es), wenn jemand an den Kühlschrank geht.


Ich denke, das (fast) einzig "gängige" Beispiel, das die meisten native Speakers verwenden würden, ist das erste.

@tofro: abgesehen davon, dass wir hier eher Perfekt als Präteritum für die Vergangenheit nutzen, könnten im richtigen Kontext mE alle diese Beispiele in der Umgangssprache auftreten.

Der Unterschied zwischen "als" und "wenn" liegt vor allem darin, ob die Gleichzeitigkeit sich in der erzählten Zeit abspielen muss oder nicht.

Ich höre zu, als er die Treppe hochkommt.

Die erzählte Zeit ist die Gegenwart, und beide Handlungen finden gleichzeitig in der Gegenwart statt. Dasselbe Prinzip funktioniert auch, wenn die erzählte Zeit beispielsweise die Vergangenheit ist:

Ich hörte zu, als er die Treppe hochkam.

Mit "wenn" wird ebenfalls eine Gleichzeitigkeit ausgedrückt, aber die beiden Handlungen müssen nicht unbedingt in der erzählten Zeit stattfinden. Es muss auch kein einmaliges Ereignis sein.

Ich höre zu, wenn er die Treppe hochkommt.

kann man auch verstehen als

Ich höre zu, jedesmal/immer wenn er die Treppe hochkommt.
Ich listen whenever/every time he comes up the stairs.

oder als

Ich höre zu, sobald er die Treppe hochkommt.
I listen as soon as he comes up the stairs.

In der letzten Version können die gleichzeitigen Ereignisse auch in der Zukunft liegen.
Noch zwei Anmerkungen: Im Deutschen verwendet man für eine zusammenhängende Abfolge von (Treppen-)Stufen den Singular, "eine Treppe". Das ist anders als im Englischen, wo auch eine einzelne Treppe mit dem Plural als "stairs" bezeichnet wird.
Und das Verb "hochkommen" klingt, zumindest meiner Erfahrung nach, hier relativ förmlich. Es ist nicht falsch, könnte aber stilistisch nicht zum restlichen Text passen. Intuitiv hätte ich eher "heraufkommen" verwendet (die Unterscheidung zwischen "herauf-" und "hinauf-" ist wieder ein ganz anderes Thema).
